# Extract the second instance of the website pattern in a string using pandas str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to extract 2nd instance of `www` website from the below string. This is in a pandas dataframe.

```
https://google.com/url?q=https://www.accenture.com/in-en/insights/software-platforms/core- 
banking-on- 
cloud&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiQ75fwvYD1AhXOYMAKHXofCeoQFnoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw02sP402HcesId4vbgOaspD
```

So I want to extract the following string and store it in a separate column.

```
https://www.accenture.com/in-en/insights/software- 
                              platforms/core- banking-on- 
   cloud&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiQ75fwvYD1AhXOYMAKHXofCeoQFnoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw02sP402HcesId4vbgOaspD
```

Final Dataframe:

```
sr.no    link_orig              link_extracted
  1       <the above string>    <the extracted string that starts from 
                                 https://www.accenture.com>
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
df['link_extracted'] = `df['link_orig'].str.contains('www.accenture.com',regex=False,na-np.NaN)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

What I am missing here? If I have to use regex then what should be the approach?

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you probably have NaNs in the `link_orig` column. That can be fixed by adding a `fillna('')` to your code.

Something like

```
df['link_extracted'] = df['link_orig'].fillna('').str.contains ...
```

That said, I'm not sure the rest of your code will do what you want. That will just return `True` is `www.accenture.com` is anywhere in the `link_orig` string.

If the link you are trying to extract always contains `www.accenture.com` then you can do this

```
df['link_extracted'] = df['link_orig'].fillna('').str.extract('(www\.accenture\.com.*)')
```

Comment: Assuming that `accenture` as a string to be passed dynamically, can I use `df['link_org'] .fillna(' ').str.extract('www\.{0}\.com.*'.format('accenture')`?

Comment: First, it probably doesn't matter in this case, but I would generally do `.fillna('')` rather than `.fillna(' ')`. The string formatting could work. I'm not 100 % positive what you're trying to do though. In the question you said you want the second instance of `www`, but `www.accenture.com` is the first occurrence of `www` in your string. Also, I fixed a typo in my answer. The extract string needs a capture group in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use `Series.str.extract()` for this. E.g:

```py
df['link_extracted'] = df['link_orig'].str.extract('http.*(http.*)')
```

This matches `http`, followed by anything, then captures `http` followed by anything.

An alternate approach would be to use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib.parse` module:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = 'https://google.com/url?q=https://www.accenture.com/in-en/insights/software-platforms/core-banking-on-cloud&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiQ75fwvYD1AhXOYMAKHXofCeoQFnoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw02sP402HcesId4vbgOaspD'
df = pd.DataFrame({'sr.no':[1], 'link_orig':[url]})

extract_q = lambda url: parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q'][0]
df['link_extracted'] = df['link_orig'].apply(extract_q)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   sr.no                                          link_orig                                     link_extracted
0      1  https://google.com/url?q=https://www.accenture...  https://www.accenture.com/in-en/insights/softw...
```

Comment: I am getting a `KeyError: 'q'`